# Take picture and name it afterwards

Tags: java, android, file, android-camera-intent

I want to take a picture with the standart system service

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

and AFTERWARDS I want to give it a custom name and directory or path (which should happen in another activity after I've taken the photo with the camera activity)

The problem is that if I create a file with all the attributes (name, path) and give it to the intent I cant do it in the activity after having taken the photo instead I would need to determine its attributes before I open the Intent(take the photo).
(as suggested in the Google article:https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath)

Should I just get the fullsize Bitmap then open the other activity and then save it and determine its attributes?

Is there a way to do it as suggested in the article but somehow the other way around?(create the File afterwards)

Let me know if you have any idea.

I apreceate any help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to take a picture with the standart system service

Your code is launching any one of hundreds of possible camera apps. The specific app might have been pre-installed by a device manufacturer, or it might be an app that the user installed.

> The problem is that if I create a file with all the attributes (name, path) and give it to the intent I cant do it in the activity after having taken the photo instead I would need to determine its attributes before I open the Intent(take the photo).

Correct.

> Should I just get the fullsize Bitmap then open the other activity and then save it and determine its attributes?

There is no means of having `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` give you a "fullsize Bitmap" directly. You can either get a *thumbnail*-sized `Bitmap` or have it write a full-sized photo to a location of your choice.

> Is there a way to do it as suggested in the article but somehow the other way around?(create the File afterwards)

No. However, there is nothing stopping you from opening the photo via its file in your activity, then modifying that photo and writing it back out. You could overwrite the original file, or you could write to some new location.

So, for example, if your concern is that you do not want the photo to be in a user-accessible location until your activity is done with it, you could pass a `Uri` to `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` that points to a private location in `getCacheDir()`, then have your activity write the final version of the photo to a file on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: Thanks for this helpful comment